# when Facebook login with Deezer, 'Unknown ID' show

Tags: deezer

Help me.
in my app, when login deezer with Facebook, that msg will show.
that msg means 'Unknown ID'. but sometimes login will be done.
sometimes login delayed and not response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PFpr.png)

Answer (score 0):

this message should be updated on our side (It's clearly not explicit) but it means that you tried to use a non-registered FB account during a LOGIN process.

:)